# iOS - UITableView in UIVIewController doesn't display all rows [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm facing a bug with my `UITableView` in `UIViewController`.
I'll try to explain what's the situation and my problem.

I have a `TabBarController` which a view is a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. I don't use a `UITableViewController` because I have some specifics controls on my `UIViewController`.

So, when my `UIViewController` isn't a child of my `TabBarController`, everything is okay : all rows are displayed correctly.

But, when I set my `UIViewController` as a child of my `TabBarController`, I have this bug : only some rows are displayed (one over threem exactly, in all scenarios).

I just don't understand what's happening. My code seems working, but only when my `UIViewController` isn't a child of my `TabBarController`.

Is there another method to add in this case ?

There is the code of my `UIViewController` :

```
class ProfileController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableChallenges: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileTabs: UISegmentedControl!

    var pageViewController : UIPageViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableChallenges.dataSource = self
        self.tableChallenges.delegate = self

        self.tableChallenges.reloadData()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("challengeCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChallengeCustomCell

        switch(self.profileTabs.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0:
                cell.challengeSuccededOrFailedImage.hidden = true
            break

            case 1:
                cell.challengeSuccededOrFailedImage.hidden = false
                cell.challengeSuccededOrFailedImage.image = UIImage(named: "challenge-succeded")
            break

            case 2:
                cell.challengeSuccededOrFailedImage.hidden = false
                cell.challengeSuccededOrFailedImage.image = UIImage(named: "challenge-failed")
            break

            case 3:
                cell.challengeSuccededOrFailedImage.hidden = true
            break

            default: break

        }

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func selectedItemChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.tableChallenges.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers ! :)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It happens with UICollectionViews as well as UITableViews. If I embed the ViewController which contains one of those views inside a UITabBarController, only some cells contain the subviews specified in Storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the long time without feedback.

I have finally found a solution to my problem. I embedded my `UIViewController` which contains the `UITableView` in a `UINavigationController`. After a few researchs, it seems to be the good hierarchy for this case.

Hope this will help somebody helse. :)

Comment: This is really late but in my case, I was using UITableViewAutomaticDimension and was setting the height to 0 for one of my sections in the estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath. So, after setting it to an estimate of 100 then the rows started showing.

Answer (score 1):

Ever since MainStory boards came out I'm  not a big fan of it, I had the same error the other night, I had to get rid of my View Controller and make a View Controller out of a .xib file.

- I delete the ViewController from my porject
- Then I went to the AppDelagate and added a variable to create my own ViewController
  `var viewController: ViewController?`
- Under the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function before the **return**
- I added the following code
  `self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
  self.viewController = ViewController(nibName:"ViewController",bundle:nil)
  var navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.viewController!)
  navController.navigationBarHidden = true
  self.window?.rootViewController = navController
  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`

Basically after drawing the window frames we created the `ViewController` and embed it in a navigation controller, then sets the navigation controller as the root view of the window.

- So then you have to create a xib file File > New > File choose IOS/User Interface; name it ViewController and create. After you can add the UITableView Controller and everything should work fine.

Comment: Sorry about sending feedback so late. I would prefer not to create an external file. If all my views could be in my storyboard, it would be perfect.

I still don't understand what's the problem. Why a UITableView in a UIViewController, embedded in a UITabBarController, shows only a few rows ? Did I make something wrong ?