# Collection View Cells not appearing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I want to display as many `collectionViewCells` with `buttons` as there are strings in my array. but when I start the simulator there is just the background of the `CollectionView`but no cells shown. What could be the error?

Here is the code from my `CollectionViewController` that I attached to the `CollectionView` in the main.storyboard:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var Array = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Array = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Array.count
}

override func
    collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        var button = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
        button.titleLabel?.text = Array[indexPath.row]

        return cell
}
```

}

These are the connections of the Collection View Controller:

[image: connections]

The View Controller on the Storyboard:

[image: viewcontroller]

Comment: It might be an auto layout issue if you are using storyboard. Can you show the screenshot of the view controller on storyboard and also the screnshots of the layout options?

Comment: I tried with auto layout disabled and there still was the same problem. What do you mean with the layout options? I added a screenshot of the view controller on storyboard

Comment: Have you remembered to set the custom class of the controller in the StoryBoard to your CollectionViewController?

Comment: Have you check if your " func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsSection section: Int) " is executing?

Comment: Is your UIViewController inside a UITabBarController? Can you please check if this question is related to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33177968/1171404

Comment: It looks harmful... `var Array = [String]()`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you set the `CollectionViewController` to the storyboard identity inspector? :)

And I would try to call the `reloadData()` after you change the data in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Hope that helps

Comment: can you specify how to set the CollectionViewController to the storyboard identity inspector?

Answer (score 4):

```
func layoutCells() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - 40)/3, height: ((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - 40)/3))
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
    }
```

Try this. Call this function from view did load. I think the problem is that your collection is not laid out correctly.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    layoutCells()
}
```

If this works you can modify the layout options to meet your needs.

Comment: Sadly there is still the same problem. Only the background is shown in the Simulator

Comment: Does it show the background of the cell or the view?

Comment: Works like a gem! However, for me, the app crashes when I insert `layoutCells()` in the `viewDidLoad()` method, so I left that part out.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, I found this that was somehow restraining the size of my cell. Hope this helps.

[image: Select the CollectionViewCell]

[image: Find this values in size inspector]

Answer (score 4):

I removed this code from my CollectionViewController.m file

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

and cell get appeared

Answer (score 3):

Problem is with setting the title to button, use the following code.

```
override func
    collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        var button = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
        //button.titleLabel?.text = Array[indexPath.row]
        button.setTitle(Array[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        return cell
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the correct reuse identifier set for the cell.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

check that you are setting CollectionView outlets (datasource , delegate) in your storyBoard as show below

[image: helpful image link]

Comment: This was the issue that I was facing.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

- Check if your cell reuse identifier is set up.
- Check if you've set the collection view subclass correctly in the storyboard.
- Put `print` statements inside your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function to see if it's being called ever.
- Not sure if this should be an issue, but `Array` is actually a type in Swift. Using that as your variable name might be messing with the logic somehow. Rename it to `array` (lowercase). I believe this is best practice for variable names anyway.
- Do something else to the cell in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, such as changing the background color. If that works, maybe there's just something wrong with what you're doing with tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsSection section: Int)`

method signature. It is wrong. It should be

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int`

and with `override` specification (because `UICollectionViewController` has own, this why you get empty collection).

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return Array.count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all check you have used this method:-

```
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
return searches.count
}
```

There’s one search per section, so the number of sections is the count of the searches array. so also we can use as per needed this method.by default we can use retuen 1

And Follow step in the Link for better soluation
[Check this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1)

Comment: The default implementation for the protocol returns 1 so it can't be it.

Comment: ohh yes @TomaszBąk  There’s one search per section, so the number of sections is the count of the searches array. so also we can use as per needed this method.And thank you correction because its help other to better understand.

Answer (score 1):

Select the `UIButton` in storyboard, check the `installed` as the bottom left in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that the cell is not hidden. Add this code below

```
    cell.isHidden = false
```

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm 7 years late but for people researching this issue...Here's the answer.

The cell was probably showing but because it wasn't configured properly , the button did not appear.

NOTE: For new developers, if you add anything to a cell (CollectionView/TableView) through storyboard you won't be able to change the values programmatically unless you create a custom cell and connect the storyboard cell to the custom cell. Then you'll have to connect the button from storyboard cell to the custom cell.

Judging by the posted problem code, The cell was not configured at all.

Study the posted problem with notes added by me to identify the errors that were made.

STEP BY STEP SOLUTION

INCORRECT

```
var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
```

// cell was declared as a UICollectionViewCell, which is basically a default empty cell. It should have been declared as a custom cell.

CORRECTION

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
```

//developer was trying to pass a cell as a button, which is telling Xcode that the cell is the same as the button which would cause a crash since that's not possible and it was forced unwrapped (as!). Another thing is that the button was created but never added to the cell, so it's a siting duck.

```
var button = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
```

ENTIRE SOLUTION

Create a new file/custom cell and connect it to the storyboard cell using the identity inspector. See image below

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBFwQ.jpg)

Connect the button from storyboard to the custom cell, then create a function to configure the button

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button:UIButton!

    func configureCell() {

        button.setTitle("Custom Text", for: .normal)
    }

}
```

Now within the cellForItem func.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    
    cell.configureCell()
    
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The items in the cell weren't showing up for me because I hadn't set tamic for each of the added subviews when programmatically adding subviews.

```
subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```