# Swift: Storyboard: UITableViewCell empty when parent UIViewController is inside UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I discovered a very strange bug when using a `UICollectionView` or a `UITableView` as children of a `UIViewController` which is part of a `UITabBarController`.

Imagine following setup:
[image: Storyboard Overview]

As you can see we have a `UITabBarController` containing the ViewControllers `MostViewedViewController` and `MostRecentViewController`.

The `MostViewedViewController` contains a `UIButton` which causes a `"Show"-Segue` to the `MostRecentViewController` when clicked.

---

The `MostRecentViewController` contains a `UITableView` which contains a 'Prototype Cell' with the Reuse-Identifier `mostRecentCellIdentifier`. The class of the ViewController is connected with the 'UITableViewDataSource' and contains following code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class MostRecentViewController : UIViewController {
    private let kReuseIdentifier = "mostRecentCellIdentifier"

    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

    internal var dataArray : [Int]? {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    }
}

extension MostRecentViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

---

Now when I open the app, the TabBarViewController shows the `MostViewedViewController`. If I click on the Button I see the following (**THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD BE**):

[image: TabBarController] **-> CKICK ->** [image: MostRecentViewController 1]

---

But when I switch to the `MostRecentViewController` by using the `TabBar` the UITableViewCells have the right background-color but don't contain any of the defined subviews (**WHY ARE THEY NOT BEING DISPLAYED ???**):

[image: MostRecentViewController 2]

---

### Here is a link to the [EXAMPLE XCODE PROJECT](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6ri6ounn0h46cto/AABi5Cwh4LmEHh9D2i2-UT4na?dl=0).

The Question might be related to [THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33177968/1171404)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug when using size classes in the constellation described above. To fix the issue select the Storyboard and then open the File-Inspector Tab:

[image: File Inspector]

Then uncheck the following option for the Storyboard:

[image: Size Classes]